# Using json storage, get the object with jquery code and save into a variable with the jquery result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using a tour system called hopscotch, We wanted to be able to make these tours on the fly and as they where written in a JSON format we added it to our database for our site.

The issue is, to point at an element we need to use an ID or jquery or js `document.querySelector("#content p")` and when I parse (with JSON.parse) this will tell me that the JSON format is invalid, which is fair, but then if I don't parse it, it goes into the variable but it does not run the js or jquery code.

I have a feeling what I am trying to do is not possible however if anyone has any clue to what I can do to get this JSON or JSON like formatted text from the database and run the Jquery when it gets to the code, and adds the results of that query into the variable.

Thanks for helping.

**EDIT**

Example JSON that I want to store in my database, at the end of the code is the command that runs the tour.

I need to get the JSON into the var `tour` which works, and as explained before wont work if there is code like `document.querySelector("#content p"),` in it.

It looks like it just adds the `document.querySelector("#content p"),` as text. So when I console the tour var it still displays it as `document.querySelector("#content p"),` and not as result of that command.

```
var tour = {
  id: "hello-hopscotch",
  steps: [
    {
      title: "My Header",
      content: "This is the header of my page.",
      target: "header",
      placement: "right"
    },
    {
      title: "My content",
      content: "Here is where I put my content.",
      target: document.querySelector("#content p"),
      placement: "bottom"
    }
  ]
};

// Starts the tour!
hopscotch.startTour(tour);
```

To get the JSON I am just running a database query and then at this time parsing it though the `JSON.parse` command into the tour variable, which is then run as above.

Plugin Website: http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/

Comment: _"JSON format is invalid"_ can you add some sample JSON? What about any other _relevant_ code? May you add a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi, I have added an edit. with code examples. I hope that helps.

Comment: Just an fyi, the object in `tour` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the "document.querySelector" part for your targets and just used "#content p"?  I recall that worked fine for me when using hopscotch in the past.  Not sure if that would solve your problem though as I never tried loading it from db.

Comment: @AlecMenconi Thanks, Thats really helpful. I wasn't aware that would work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah I'm aware of that, that is example code, Mine is correct.

Comment: @simonr2 that's good. I can only discuss what you share.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thats fair, Don't take that as me having a go at you. I just wanted to note that I realised that it was not correct JSON.

Comment: As a general comment, That works great, however I still have the patential issue of not being able to use code in it.

For example there are call backs and other commands that you can add. `onStart: function() {
            $('#article').addClass('selected');
         }`

But this wont fit into the JSON parser. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @simonr2 sorry. Text doesn't convey tone very well. -- Sadly JSON cannot store objects (like HTML elements), so I would advise storing the selector as a string, and then using a function to restore it to an object after `JSON.parse` has run.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks, I'll what I can do.